# Using select() and fgets() to access information from a serial port

Tags: c++, input, serial-port

This is a followup to this question:  [How to wait for input from the serial port in the middle of a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656579/how-to-wait-for-input-from-the-serial-port-in-the-middle-of-a-program)

I am writing a program to control an Iridium modem that needs to wait for a response from the serial port in the middle of the program in order to verify that the correct response was given.  In order to accomplish this, a user recommended I use the `select()` command to wait for this input.

However, I have run into some difficulty with this approach.  Initially, `select()` would return the value indicated a timeout on the response every time (even though the modem was sending back the correct responses, which I verified with another program running at the same time).  Now, the program stops after one iteration, even with the correct response sent back from the modem.

```
 //setting the file descriptor to the port
int fd = open(portName.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

if (fd == -1)
{
  /*
   * Could not open the port.
   */

  perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");
}
else
 fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

FILE *out = fopen(portName.c_str(), "w");//sets the serial port
FILE *in = fopen(portName.c_str(), "r");


fd_set fds;
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(fd, &fds);
struct timeval timeout = { 10, 0 }; /* 10 seconds */
//int ret = select(fd+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
/* ret == 0 means timeout, ret == 1 means descriptor is ready for reading,
 ret == -1 means error (check errno) */

char buf[100];

int i =0; 
while(i<(sizeof(messageArray)/sizeof(messageArray[0])))
{
  //creates a string with the AT command that writes to the module
  std::string line1("AT+SBDWT=");
  line1+=convertInt( messageArray[i].numChar);
  line1+=" ";
  line1+=convertInt(messageArray[i].packetNumber);
  line1+=" ";
  line1+=messageArray[i].data;
  line1+=std::string("\r\n");

  //creates a string with the AT command that initiates the SBD session
  std::string line2("AT+SBDI");
  line2+=std::string("\r\n");

  fputs(line1.c_str(), out); //sends to serial port

  //usleep(7000000);     
  int ret =select(fd+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  /* ret == 0 means timeout, ret == 1 means descriptor is ready for reading,
 ret == -1 means error (check errno) */

  if (ret ==1){
fgets (buf ,sizeof(buf), in);
//add code to check if response is correct
  }
  else if(ret == 0) {
perror("timeout error ");
  }
  else if (ret ==-1) {
perror("some other error");
  }

  fputs(line2.c_str(), out); //sends to serial port

  //usleep(7000000); //Pauses  between the addition of each packet.
  int ret2 = select(fd+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  /* ret == 0 means timeout, ret == 1 means descriptor is ready for reading,
 ret == -1 means error (check errno) */

  if(ret2 == 0) {
perror("timeout error ");
  }
  else if (ret2 ==-1) {
perror("some other error");
  }

  i++;
}
```

Comment: You are trying this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Why are you passing (fd+1) in the first argument of select function? Try passing 1 instead as the first argument of select is count of descriptors in fd array although this argument is ignored in windows

Comment: @Muhammad: `(fd + 1)` is correct, read the `select` manual page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't using the same file handle for read/write/select, which is somewhat strange.

You are not resetting your fd_sets, which are modified by `select` and would have all of your fds unset in the case of a timeout, making the next call timeout by default (as you are asking for no fds).

you are also using buffered IO, which is bound to create headaches in this case. eg. `fgets` waits for either `EOF` (which won't occur), or a newline, reading all the while. It will block until it gets its newline, so may keep you hanging indefinitely if that never occurs.
It may also read more than it needs into the buffer, messing up your `select` read signal (you have data in the buffer, but select will time out, since there's nothing to read on the filehandle).

Bottom line is this:

- use `FD_SET` in the loop to set/reset your fd sets, also reset your timeout, as `select` may modify it.
- use a single handle for read/write/select, instead of multiple handles, eg. open file with `fopen(..., "w+")` or `open(..., O_RDWR)`
- if still using `fopen`, try disabling buffering using `setvbuf` with the `_IONBF` buffering option.
- otherwise, use `open`/`read`/`write` instead of `fopen` etc.

I will note that part of this was mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656579/how-to-wait-for-input-from-the-serial-port-in-the-middle-of-a-program/6656664#6656664) to your previous question.

Answer (score -1):

You should perhaps use fflush() on your output file stream.