# C, linux - Suspend a thread until some data arrives

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, file-descriptor

I would like to create thread which will be waiting for data from file descriptor (Serial Port). In that time I must be able to send data through this port.

I was trying to use *pthread* and *poll*, but program is hanging (sleeping) from the start and even don't do first command in main function.

The problem is for sure with poll function - when I limited a time all instructions were performed after this time.

Here is my code:

```
#define SERIAL_DEVICE "/dev/ttyUSB0"
#define SERIAL_BAUD 2400

#include <wiringSerial.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <poll.h>


//deklaracje
void *receiving( void *ptr )
{
    printf("New thread started");
    int fd= (int)ptr;
    struct pollfd fds[1];
    fds[0].fd = fd;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN ;
    int pollrc=-1;

    while(1)
    {
        pollrc = poll( fds, 1, -1);
        if (pollrc < 0)
        {
            perror("poll");
        }
        else if( pollrc > 0)
        {
            if( fds[0].revents & POLLIN )
            {
                unsigned char buff[1024];
                ssize_t rc = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff) );
                if (rc > 0)
                {
                    printf("RX: %s",buff);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = serialOpen(SERIAL_DEVICE, SERIAL_BAUD);

    if (fd<0)
    {
        printf("Serial opening error");
        return 1;
    }

    pthread_t serialReceiver;
    printf("-----");
    int thr=pthread_create(&serialReceiver,NULL,receiving,fd);
    printf("%i",thr);
    if(thr!=0)
    {
        printf("Error during creating serialReceiver thread.");
        return 1;
    }

    int status;
    pthread_join(serialReceiver,(void **)&status);

    printf("%i",status);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When using `poll`, you don't need a separate thread.

Comment: So quick advice for beginer (can be code example). What is the best way to triger action when I will receive a data? I would like to have opportunity to send data during waiting for something to receive. As you noticed I will use only one fd.

Comment: You wouldn't know how far it got into the main function with those printf()s. They will buffer the output and you won't see it until they are flushed. That happens on newlines (which your printf()s are missing), explicitly with fflush() or on program exit (which is why you're seeing something when you add timeouts).

Comment: @Wojtek: What will cause you to send data?  A timer?  Then use `poll` with a timeout (on the main thread), if it exits with timeout, then send.  Input on another fd?  Then pass both descriptors to `poll`, if the serial port wakes you then read, if the other wakes you then send.

Comment: @AndreasBombe - my example was fine. When i added new line symbols to printf it is working as I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) to wait on a file descriptor until there is some data to read.

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681492/using-select-and-fgets-to-access-information-from-a-serial-port) about the usage.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm late. The problem you have is not your poll, but actually your printf. When you use read, it doesn't put a null terminator at the end of your string. It instead returns the length of the string. When using printf with read, you want to tell printf to stop after the amount of characters that read says to write, by using `printf("RX: %*.s", rc, buff)`. Now, it will write `rc` characters instead of writing until it finds the null terminator.